# What does braces "{ }" inside argument of an arrow function mean

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I know, for multiple arguments or single argument with type, we have to parenthesize arguments of an arrow function. e.g.

`.map( (arg1, arge2) => returnValue )` or `.map( (arg1: ArgType) => returnValue )`

And if we intend to return a *json* literal from shorter syntax arrow function, we've to parenthesize it. e.g.

`.map( (arg1, arge2) => ({ a: 1, b: 2}) )`

**But**, what does the following do?

`.map( ({ value }) => value )`

I stumbled across it in a TypeScript codebase, don't yet know if it is also supported in ES6.

Comment: it's object destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)  in ES2015 it is basically equivalent to

```
let arr = [{ value: "" }]
arr.map(({ value }) => value )
// same as 
arr.map(o => { let value = o.value; return value; }  )
```